# Unmarshal JAXB-Annotated Classes from JSON using Jersey and Jackson

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey, jackson

I have a class that has JAXB and bean validation annotations, much like the following:

```
@XmlType(namespace = "urn:com:company:assessment")
@XmlRootElement
public class Assessment
{
    // ...

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1,
          message = "Assessment requires at least one address.")
    @Valid
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AddressesAdapter.class)
    public synchronized Set<Address> getAddresses()
    {
        return this.addresses;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Jersey marshals this class to and unmarshals from XML just fine; however, Jersey can't unmarshal from JSON correctly. I've set breakpoints within the `AddressesAdapter` class, and noticed that the `unmarshal()` method is never invoked when unserializing JSON.

Despite whether configuring Jersey using natural notation or otherwise, if I create an `@XmlAnyElement`-annotated property, I get `addresses` elements that should have been unmarshalled using the adapter.

If I use Jackson directly and register its `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` provider, I get exceptions when attempting to unmarshal from JSON:

```
Nov 2, 2011 10:07:41 AM com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse getEntity
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class com.company.Assessment, and Java type class com.company.Assessment, and MIME media type application/json was not found
Nov 2, 2011 10:07:41 AM com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse getEntity
SEVERE: The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
```

(`JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` is not listed.)

Does anyone have an idea as to how I may marshal my JAXB-annotated classes as both XML and JSON without having to create `MessageBodyReader`s and `MessageBodyWriter`s?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add jersey-json to your project dependencies.

Comment: I have, and as I mentioned, I configured it using natural notation, mapped, etc., and it doesn't work. I tried it using Jackson directly, and that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have stumbled upon the same problem as I did yesterday. I was confused by the Jersey documentation and didn't understand all the requirements that are needed.

I have created a small Jersey Client that gets a JSON resource from a Rails server and unmarshalles it into a POJO but I could not get it to work yesterday but today I was successful!

First there is one jar missing in the Jersey requirements documentation, the Jackson XML Compability jar and also the documentation is confusing. I wrote a small bugg report on that http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-803

Make sure you have the following jars when running your program:

- jackson-core-asl.jar
- jackson-mapper-asl.jar
- jackson-jaxrs.jar
- jackson-xc.jar
- jettison.jar
- activation.jar
- stax-api.jar
- jersey-json.jar

You will also require JAXB 2.x support but thats part of Java SE 6.

Let me know if this works for you, if not I can post my JSON client code.